# Is casting a 2D array into a 1D array defined/portable?

Tags: arrays, c

While the following code behaves as expected on Godbolt, I'm wondering if, from a standard perspective, casting `int [n][m] -> int [n*m]` was allowed.

```
#define ROW 2
#define COL 10

void test(int arr[ROW * COL]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (ROW * COL); i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}

int main() {

    // build an array
    int arr[ROW][COL];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = i * 10 + j;
        }
    }

    // Make the conversion
    int* converted = (int*)arr; //< The conversion
    test(converted);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to try it: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdbool.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%23define+COUNT_OF(x)+%5C%0A++++((sizeof(x)+/+sizeof(0+%5Bx%5D))+/+((size_t)(!!(sizeof(x)+%25+sizeof(0+%5Bx%5D)))))%0A%0A%23define+ROW+2%0A%23define+COL+10%0A%0Avoid+test(int+arr%5BROW+*+COL%5D)+%7B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+(ROW+*+COL)%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22%25d%5Cn%22,+arr%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++//+build+an+array%0A++++int+arr%5BROW%5D%5BCOL%5D%3B%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+ROW%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++for+(int+j+%3D+0%3B+j+%3C+COL%3B+j%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++++++arr%5Bi%5D%5Bj%5D+%3D+i+*+10+%2B+j%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++//+test%0A++++int*+converted+%3D+(int*)arr%3B+//%3C+The+conversion%0A++++test(converted)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.24406705856738,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:33.60073931216669,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:33.06592735449999,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:tool,i:(args:%27%27,argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,monacoEditorHasBeenAutoOpened:%271%27,monacoEditorOpen:%271%27,monacoStdin:%271%27,stdin:%27%27,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,toolId:PVS-Studio,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27PVS-Studio+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:33.33333333333333,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:46.75593294143262,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Yes.  Arrays are defined as consecutive elements, so your array of arrays is consecutive ints.

Comment: @stark: The fact the underlying memory layout is defined to be the same does not mean the C rules for types, aliasing, and pointer arithmetic support it.

Comment: The cast isn’t int [n][m] -> int [n\*m], it’s actually int (*)[10] -> int *. Both are simply pointers to int, perfectly legal.

Comment: @PaulLynch: `int (*)[10]` is not a pointer to `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are correct that this is UB since the pointer arithmetic isn't specified to work out of bounds. But as far as aliasing goes, it is quite clear (6.5): "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the
following types:" /--/ "- an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members". `b[i]` is a lvalue expression of type `int` and so the compiler cannot assume that it does not change `a` since it's an aggregate with `int` among its members.